# Problems with namespaces. Can't found the class

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm a newbie with the namespaces but I really don't understand why this simple code is not working!.

**protocoloWt/schemas/AuthorSchema.php**

```
namespace protocoloWt\schemas;

class AuthorSchema
{
    protected $resourceType = 'people';

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getId($author)
    {
        /** @var Author $author */
        return $author->authorId;
    }

    public function getAttributes($author)
    {
        /** @var Author $author */
        return [
            'first_name' => $author->firstName,
            'last_name'  => $author->lastName,
        ];
    }
}
```

**protocoloWt/App.php**

```
namespace protocoloWt;
use protocoloWt\schemas\AuthorSchema;

$a = new AuthorSchema();
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'protocoloWt\schemas\AuthorSchema' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wt.uptkd\protocoloWt\app.php

I think the code is correct and should works, right?, but then why do I get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use a (PSR0/4) autoloader (like composer e.g.) you have to import the file  protocoloWt/schemas/AuthorSchema.php in the app.php file.

Docs of composer-autoloading:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Thank you so much!. I didn't know it. Would either of the two options be good or is there one better than the other?

Comment: I think you mean PSR-0/4. PSR-0 is deprecated also.

Comment: @Nebur81 as naththedeveloper mentioned PSR-4 is the standard to choose:

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces doesn't mean auto loading which means you have to either include/require the class

```
require_once('protocoloWt/schemas/AuthorSchema.php');
```

or setup an autoloader. If you want to do this I could give you a code example! :)